# Google Analytics showing cannot resolve a method in android?

Tags: android, google-analytics, android-library

In my application i am using Google Analytics.but GoogleAnalytics showing cannot resolve a method.

build:gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
    compile project(':mobihelp_sdk_android_v1.3.1')
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar')
    compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.5.0'

}
```

Manifest file:

```
<application
            android:name="com.reloadapp.reload.fragments.Application"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.globalConfigResource"
                android:resource="@xml/analytics_global_config" />
    </application>
```

please help me out. which lib i need to add?

import:

```
import java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import android.util.Log;

import org.acra.ACRA;
import org.acra.ReportingInteractionMode;
import org.acra.annotation.ReportsCrashes;
import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.analytics.ExceptionParser;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.HitBuilders;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Google Analytics jar is not recommended any more, you should use the latest [Google Play Services 6.5](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
...

dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:6.5.87'
}
```

For more reference setting up Google Analytics SDK v4 for Android: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

Comment: thanks for reply. i imported that..but LogLevel showing error. analytics.getLogger().setLogLevel(Logger.LogLevel.VERBOSE);

Comment: Please give the exact exception you get from your logcat, did you remove `compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar')`?

Comment: s i removed that lib. it is not a run time error...:"LogLevel" showing(redcolor) in class file itself

Comment: I guess you are missing the Google Play Services libraries. Open your Android SDK Manager and check that both 'Google Play serivces' and 'Google Repository' are updated.

Comment: No problem, it only forces log level, should not affect your analytics logic. Anyway it should be resolved once u updated those libraries in SDK manager.

Comment: ok then i removed that line hidro... because it is not resolved.okay?